Why different promise state results (using Promise.race) inside and outside a setTimeout?
How do the promises (p1, p2, p3) get executed differently in the getStates() function outside the setTimeout and inside the setTimeout?
const p1 = new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(100), 100));
const p2 = new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(200), 200));
const p3 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej(300), 100));

async function getStates() {
  console.log(await promiseState(p1));
  console.log(await promiseState(p2));
  console.log(await promiseState(p3));
}

console.log("Immediately after initiation:");
getStates();
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("After waiting for 100ms:");
  getStates();
}, 100);

The promiseState function is from MDN and uses Promise.race:
function promiseState(promise) {
  const pendingState = { status: "pending" };

  return Promise.race([promise, pendingState]).then(
    (value) =>
      value === pendingState ? value : { status: "fulfilled", value },
    (reason) => ({ status: "rejected", reason }),
  );
}

This is all an example from the MDN Promise.race page.
I thought all the Promises should return the pendingState object but that's not the case in the setTimeout function.

"I thought all the Promises should return the pendingState object" only if they are created right now. They won't be pending after the promise settles.

What is promiseState? Is that your own function?

@Johan - It's from the MDN page (the OP says this really unclearly).

@T.J.Crowder Found it, thanks, and good answer below!

You aren't racing any Promises in your code? What does the question title have to do with the body of the question?

@JaredSmith - Yeah, it was fairly confusing. :-) The promiseState function from MDN the OP was using uses Promise.race, but they'd left it out of the question. I've edited it in for them, and tried to make the title more indicative of the question.


how does the promises(p1, p2, p3) gets executed differently

This is a key misunderstanding a lot of people have about promises. A promise is not executed. A promise just reports on something that's being done, it doesn't do the thing. It's a standard way of observing the result of an asynchronous action.
In that code, the asynchronous actions are the timers. The timers are started when you create the promises (the first three lines of code). The function you pass new Promise is called synchronously, before new Promise returns the promise. That function's job is to start the asynchronous work the promise will report on. So the work each of those three promises is reporting on is started once, right at the beginning, not later when you observe them via getStates.
After you start those timers, you check the promise states twice:

Right away: This is before any of the timers has had a chance to fire, so all the promises show pending.
100ms later: At this point, two of your promises have been settled (p1 is fulfilled after 100ms, and p3 is rejected after 100ms) and one of them is still pending (since p2 isn't settled for 200ms). So you see the result that p1 is fulfilled, p2 is pending, and p3 is rejected.

The key thing is that the promise timers start when you create the promises, not later.

All that said, detecting the state of a promise is a bad idea. That's why promises don't have a built-in way to do it. Instead, write your code such that it reacts to a promise's fulfillment and/or rejection, without worrying about the state of the promise when you set up those reactions. A function like promiseState is an anti-pattern other than a very limited use in the course of trying to understand how promises work. And even then, it can be misleading — the information may be out of date by the time you see it.

"detecting the state of a promise is a very bad idea" for why - there is usually no reason to do it because any promise is assumed to complete in the future. Thus all code handling it would similarly have to make the same assumption. This always works correctly. If that assumption is broken then that means you have some code which expects a promise to have finished and handling as such. And synchronous promises unleash Zalgo

thanks TJ I was confused when I first have a look at it on mdn.
BUT one last thing I want to ask is :
is the reason for the promises returning pendingState in the first getStates() function call execution of the code before 100ms

@leac - Yes, that's right. None of the three promises is settled until 100ms (or so) after they're created, but the first call to getStates happens immediately after they're created.
